# "ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_world.launch.py" results in package not found

Tags: simulation, ros, ros2, gazebo-simu

These are the commands that were used:

```
$ source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash
ROS_DISTRO was set to 'noetic' before. Please make sure that the environment does not mix paths from different distributions.
$ export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:~/turtlebot3_ws/src/turtlebot3_simulations/turtlebot3_gazebo/models
$ export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger
$ ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_world.launch.py
Package 'turtlebot3_gazebo' not found: "package 'turtlebot3_gazebo' not found, searching: ['/opt/ros/foxy']"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that a sub-directory is missing in the path?

> `export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:~/turtlebot3_ws/src/turtlebot3/turtlebot3_simulations/turtlebot3_gazebo/models`

Alternatively, you may use the following if you do not require a workspace:

> `export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:/opt/ros/foxy/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/models`

Comment: You should keep the content of the answer limited to what is needed. The reference to the site is not needed, so please edit the answer to reflect this.